# Making an image, inside a clickable div, unresponsive to the action

Tags: javascript, css

So currently I have a image inside a div in such a way:

```
<div onclick="doSomething()">

   <img onclick="doSomethingElse()" src="image.png"/>

</div>
```

But clicking on the image calls both `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()`. I'd only like it to `doSomethingElse()`.

I "need" to have the containing div "`doSomething()`" so getting rid of that is not an option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of `doSomethingElse()`, call [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation).

```
var doSomethingElse = function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately you answered that so quickly that I can't accept the answer but I'll accept it as soon as I can. Worked perfectly.